# Two structs, one references another

Tags: struct

```
typedef struct Radios_Frequencia {
    char tipo_radio[3];
    int qt_radio;
    int frequencia;

}Radiof;
typedef  struct Radio_Cidade  {
    char nome_cidade[30];
    char nome_radio[30];
    char dono_radio[3];
    int numero_horas;
    int audiencia;
    Radiof *fre;

}R_cidade;



void Cadastrar_Radio(R_cidade**q){
    printf("%d\n",i);

    q[0]=(R_cidade*)malloc(sizeof(R_cidade));
    printf("informa a frequencia da radio\n");
    scanf("%d",&q[0]->fre->frequencia);  //problem here
    printf("%d\n",q[0]->fre->frequencia); // problem here




}
```

i want to know why this function `void Cadastrar_Radio(R_cidade**q)` does not print the data

Answer (score 1):

You allocated storage for your primary structure but not the secondary one. Change

```
q[0]=(R_cidade*)malloc(sizeof(R_cidade));
```

to:

```
q[0]=(R_cidade*)malloc(sizeof(R_cidade));
q[0]->fre = malloc(sizeof(Radiof));
```

which will allocate both. Without that, there's a very good chance that `fre` will point off into never-never land (as in "you can never never tell what's going to happen since it's undefined behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

You've allocated some storage, but you've not properly initialized any of it.

You won't get anything reliable to print until you put reliable values into the structures.

Additionally, as [PaxDiablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14860/paxdiablo) also pointed out, you've allocated the space for the `R_cidade` structure, but not for the `Radiof` component of it.  You're using `scanf()` to read a value into space that has not been allocated; that is not reliable - undefined behaviour at best, but most usually core dump time.

Note that although the two types are linked, the C compiler most certainly doesn't do any allocation of `Radiof` simply because `R_cidade` mentions it.  It can't tell whether the pointer in `R_cidade` is meant to be to a single structure or the start of an array of structures, for example, so it cannot tell how much space to allocate.  Besides, you might not want to initialize that structure every time - you might be happy to have left pointing nowhere (a null pointer) except in some special circumstances known only to you.

You should also verify that the memory allocation succeeded, or use a memory allocator that guarantees never to return a null or invalid pointer.  Classically, that might be a cover function for the standard `malloc()` function:

```
#undef NDEBUG
#include <assert.h>

void *emalloc(size_t nbytes)
{
    void *space = malloc(nbytes);
    assert(space != 0);
    return(space);
}
```

That's crude but effective.  I use non-crashing error reporting routines of my own devising in place of the assert:

```
#include "stderr.h"

void *emalloc(size_t nbytes)
{
    void *space = malloc(nbytes);
    if (space == 0)
        err_error("Out of memory\n");
    return space;
}
```